# How do I create a button/label with dismiss?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to create a button/label with an onclick event that does some functionality. However I want to be able to give the user the option to remove the button/label if they want.This is what I did:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-   click="doSomething()">Help<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deleteThisButton()"></span></button>
```

Now if I do this both functions get called. How do I get it fire only one based on where the user clicked.

Comment: [`event.stopPropogation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the click event propagating to the button element. You can achieve this by passing the click event object ($event) to your deleteThisButton function. I've also included code to hide the button:

```
$scope.deleteThisButton = function($event) {
  $event.stopPropagation();
  angular.element($event.target).parent().css('visibility','hidden');
};
```

Change your HTML to this in order to pass the $event object to the function:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="doSomething()">Help
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deleteThisButton($event)"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('.glyphicon-remove').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!